# How can I find out if there is some file being played in AudioPlayer?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why following code doesn't work with me? :S

```
AudioPlayer.player.start(file1);
while(AudioPlayer.player.isAlive()) {}
AudioPlayer.player.start(file2);
```

I want to play my files one-by-one :S

Comment: where does the audioplayer come from?

Comment: I think the player still alive after the execution of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to `sun.audio.AudioPlayer`. If so, you should be aware that the `sun.*` classes are for use by the JRE only; you should look in the `javax.sound.*` packages instead. (See also [the Java tutorial on sound](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/)).

Having said that, the `isAlive()` method is on the `Thread` class, and since the audioplayer thread sticks around, this method never returns false.

I would try to detect the end of the song by looking to see whether the underlying `InputStream` has been closed (e.g. by overriding the `close()` method). Alternatively, you could make an `InputStream` which sequences the two input streams you are trying to play.

Comment: "I would try to detect the end of the song by looking to see whether the underlying InputStream has been closed (e.g. by overriding the close() method). Alternatively, you could make an InputStream which sequences the two input streams you are trying to play." hm... i cant quite understand what do you mean...

Comment: The AudioPlayer will close the input stream containing your song when it has finished playing it. You can detect this by overriding the close method in your input stream implementation, and setting a flag.

Comment: Seriously, you are better off using the javax.sound.* ones. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/chapter4.html